# Change versionCode using Android Gradle

Tags: android, android-manifest, gradle

I'm trying to auto increment versionCode in my `build.gradle`. But it doesn't work. Then I've tried to simply overwrite versionCode, e.g. `versionCode 20` and still it's not updated. Checked both original `AndroidManifest.xml` and packaged in apk.

Full `build.gradle`:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://mente.github.io/facebook-api-android-aar"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
dependencies {
    //provided by android gradle plugin
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'

    compile 'com.facebook:facebook-android-sdk:3.0.2@aar'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.+'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:3.+'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

def getVersionCode() {
    println "Hello getVersionCode"
    def manifestFile = file("AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def version = ++Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    println sprintf("Returning version %d", version)
    return version
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode getVersionCode()
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '1.6'
}
```

Also my debug lines from getVersionCode function are not printed out. Looks like `defaultConfig` section is ignored. I know there's [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448565/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle) here on SO. But still wondering why built-in `android.defaultConfig.versionCode` doesn't work?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/17525195/539284

Comment: @sealskej i've mentioned this solution in my question

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your function name to something else other than getVersionCode(). I ran into the same problem and changed my function name to something else and it worked

```
def getVersionCodeFromFileAndIncrement() {
     println "Hello getVersionCodeFromFileAndIncrement"
     def manifestFile = file("AndroidManifest.xml")
     def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
     def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
     def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
     matcher.find()
     def version = ++Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
     println sprintf("Returning version %d", version)
     return "$version"
}
```

Comment: Where does this presume that AndroidManifest.xml lives??

Answer (score 3):

if you would like to have a versdionCode, what is increasing every time, when building the app, I using the time.

def getBuildVersionCode() 
 {

> ```
> def date = new Date()
> def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd')
> def formattedSeconds = date.format('HHmmssSSS')
> def formatInt = formattedDate as int;
> def SecondsInt = formattedSeconds as int;
> return (formatInt + SecondsInt) as int
> ```
>
> }

or maybe a better one:

```
def getVersionCode() {
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
return formattedDate
}
```

defaultConfig {

> ```
>    versionCode getBuildVersionCode()
>    minSdkVersion 16
>    targetSdkVersion 18
> ```
>
> }

Comment: The maximum value on the Play store is 2100000000, so be careful trying to use the second example.

Answer (score 2):

This case [was described](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manifest-entries) in official android gradle plugin ducumentation:

> **Note:** Do not use function names that could conflict with existing
>   getters in the given scope. For instance instance defaultConfig { ...}
>   calling getVersionName() will automatically use the getter of
>   defaultConfig.getVersionName() instead of the custom method.

Comment: Not sure it's related to function name. I've used simple version code 20 - with still no luck