# Autoincrement VersionCode with gradle extra properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm building an Android app with gradle. Until now I used the Manifest file to increase the versionCode, but I would like to read the versionCode from an external file and depending if it is the release flavor or the debug flavor increase the versionCode. I tried the extra properties, but you can't save them, which means that next time I build it I'm getting the same versionCode.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
project.ext{
    devVersionCode = 13
    releaseVersionCode = 1
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':Cropper')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

def getReleaseVersionCode() {
    def version = project.releaseVersionCode + 1
    project.releaseVersionCode = version
    println sprintf("Returning version %d", version)
    return version
}

def getDevVersionCode() {
    def version = project.devVersionCode + 1
    project.devVersionCode = version
    println sprintf("Returning version %d", version)
    return version
}


def getLastVersioName(versionCode) {
    return "0.0." + versionCode
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig null
            zipAlign false
        }
        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            packageName = 'com.swisscom.docsafe.debug'
            versionCode getDevVersionCode()
            versionName getLastVersioName(project.devVersionCode)
        }
        prod {
            packageName = 'com.swisscom.docsafe'
            versionCode getReleaseVersionCode()
            versionName getLastVersioName(project.releaseVersionCode)
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33637600/348189

Comment: Another option (a set-and-forget approach): https://medium.com/@passsy/use-different-build-numbers-for-every-build-automatically-using-a-gradle-script-35577cd31b19

Comment: One-liner with your choice of Gradle plugins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61718437/4548500

Answer (score 239, accepted):

> I would like to read the versionCode from an external file

I am sure that there are any number of possible solutions; here is one:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1

        versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode code
            versionName "1.1"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    // rest of android block goes here
}
```

This code expects an existing `version.properties` file, which you would create by hand before the first build to have `VERSION_CODE=8`.

This code simply bumps the version code on each build -- you would need to extend the technique to handle your per-flavor version code.

You can see [the Versioning sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/Versioning) that demonstrates this code.

Comment: How to enable this version incrementing only while making release builds?

Comment: @Piotr: If you mean "only increment the number on a release build", that should be possible, though I don't know the details. Personally, since there are ~2 billion version codes available, I'm assuming I won't run out. :-)

Comment: @Piotr you would create a task which seperately increments the version code then do something like `assembleRelease.finalizedBy incrementVersion` or something similar. I will post my code once i've tidied it.

Comment: Using a custom task you can just do something like `./gradlew incrementVersionCode build`. Tasks called sequentially in this way will stop as soon as any of the tasks fail.

Comment: As @chris.jenkins is still tiding his code :p Here is the above in task and method form https://gist.github.com/doridori/544c24509be236c11fd5 which can be used inside the android DSL with `versionCode getIncrementingVersionCode()`

Comment: any way to read the version code from within the application code and append it to the generated apk file name ?

Comment: @Hakim: I do not know what "within the application code" means in this context. But, in terms of modifying the APK name to have version information, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28320434/115145

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins : do you have worked on increment build version only when signing app?

Comment: Any pointer how can we push this version.properties to the git after build?

Comment: @AmitK.Saha: Um, the same way that you commit and push any other `git` changes, I guess. That's outside the scope of this particular Gradle snippet (which BTW is >5 years old and may be out of date).

Comment: Yes, my question is definitely out of scope. It was more intended from Ci/CD perspective (Looper build) but figured it out already. Thanks!

Comment: @AmitK.Saha hello Amit, i'm trying to do the same thing, how did you manage to use the script with a CI/CD tool?

Comment: Are you using looper script?

Comment: @AmitK.Saha i'm using BitBucket Pipelines

Comment: @y.allam, sorry can't help about it.

Comment: Same solution in Kotlin DSL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55283044/970422

Answer (score 98):

Here comes a modernization of my previous answer which can be seen below. This one is running with **Gradle 4.4** and **Android Studio 3.1.1**.

What this script does:

- Creates a **version.properties** file if none exists (up vote Paul Cantrell's answer below, which is where I got the idea from if you like this answer)
- For each build, debug release or any time you press the run button in Android Studio the VERSION_BUILD number increases.
- Every time you assemble a release your Android **versionCode** for the play store increases and your **patch number** increases.
- *Bonus: After the build is done copies your apk to `projectDir/apk` to make it more accessible.*

This script will create a version number which looks like `v1.3.4 (123)` and build an apk file like **AppName-v1.3.4.apk**.

```
Major version ⌄       ⌄ Build version
             v1.3.4 (123)
  Minor version ⌃|⌃ Patch version
```

**Major version:** Has to be changed manually for bigger changes.

**Minor version:** Has to be changed manually for slightly less big changes.

**Patch version:** Increases when running `gradle assembleRelease`

**Build version:** Increases every build

**Version Number:** Same as *Patch version*, this is for the version code which Play Store needs to have increased for each new apk upload.

Just change the content in the comments labeled 1 - 3 below and the script should do the rest. :)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def value = 0
    Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    if (!versionPropsFile.exists()) {
        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = "0"
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = "0"
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = "-1" // I set it to minus one so the first build is 0 which isn't super important. 
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    }

    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    if ('assembleRelease' in runTasks) {
        value = 1
    }

    def mVersionName = ""
    def mFileName = ""

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = (versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value).toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = (versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value).toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = (versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1).toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        // 1: change major and minor version here
        mVersionName = "v1.0.${versionProps['VERSION_PATCH']}"
        // 2: change AppName for your app name
        mFileName = "AppName-${mVersionName}.apk"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 27
            applicationId "com.example.appname" // 3: change to your package name
            versionCode versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger()
            versionName "${mVersionName} Build: ${versionProps['VERSION_BUILD']}"
        }

    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    if ('assembleRelease' in runTasks) {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                if (output.outputFile != null && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                    outputFileName = mFileName
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task copyApkFiles(type: Copy){
        from 'build/outputs/apk/release'
        into '../apk'
        include mFileName
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        assembleRelease.doLast {
            tasks.copyApkFiles.execute()
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}
```

## ====================================================

**INITIAL ANSWER:**

I want the versionName to increase automatically as well. So this is just an addition to the answer by CommonsWare which worked perfectly for me. This is what works for me

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode code
    versionName "1.1." + code
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
```

**EDIT:**

As I am a bit lazy I want my versioning to work as automatically as possible. What I want is to have a **Build Version** that increases with each build, while the **Version Number** and **Version Name** only increases when I make a release build.

This is what I have been using for the past year, the basics are from CommonsWare's answer and my previous answer, plus some more. This results in the following versioning:

Version Name: **1.0.5 (123)** --> Major.Minor.Patch (Build), Major and Minor are changed manually.

In build.gradle:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        def value = 0

        def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
        if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
            value = 1;
        }

        def versionMajor = 1
        def versionMinor = 0
        def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
        def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        def versionNumber = versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode versionNumber
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild}) Release"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def fileNaming = "apk/RELEASES"
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def outputFile = output.outputFile
                    if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                        output.outputFile = new File(getProject().getRootDir(), "${fileNaming}-${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}-${outputFile.name}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    ...
}

...
```

Patch and versionCode is increased if you assemble your project through the terminal with **'assemble'**, **'assembleRelease'** or **'aR'** which creates a new folder in your project root called apk/RELEASE so you don't have to look through build/outputs/more/more/more to find your apk.

Your version properties would need to look like this:

```
VERSION_NUMBER=1
VERSION_BUILD=645
VERSION_PATCH=1
```

Obviously start with 0. :)

Comment: The second 'variant.outputs.each { output ->' can be removed, with the corresponding '}'.

Comment: This is causing all my builds to be in x86_64 native code only

Comment: @Chisko I doubt this piece of the gradle code is the cause. Ask a new question and share your gradle code and we can try to figure out whats wrong. :)

Comment: @just_user here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198586/android-build-tools-only-builds-x86-64-no-matter-what-apk-runs-installed-via-ad I really appreciate it!

Comment: I can now confirm this was not the root cause. My apologies.

Comment: I seem to need to find `':app:assembleRelease'` instead of just `'assembleRelease'` in runTasks.

Comment: So what is the difference between VERSION_PATCH and VERSION_NUMBER?

Comment: @AlexanderGavriliuk its the version code used by the play store which constantly needs to increase for every upload. The patch number will probably be reset if you increase the major or minor version. The version number should never, could never be reset if you upload the app to the play store with the same package name.

Comment: Won't this prevent incremental builds? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#use_static_build_properties

Answer (score 43):

A slightly tightened-up version of CommonsWare's excellent answer creates the version file if it doesn't exist:

```
def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
if(versionPropsFile.exists())
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
def code = (versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] ?: "0").toInteger() + 1
versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

defaultConfig {
    versionCode code
    versionName "1.1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
}
```

Comment: where is the part about creating the version file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: `if(versionPropsFile.exists())` ensures that it doesn’t explode if the file isn’t there. `versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null) ` overwrites the file regardless of whether it exists already.

Comment: Had to check what `?:` meant in Groovy. The [Elvis operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_elvis_operator) is a shortening of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 41):

I looked at a few options to do this, and ultimately decided it was simpler to just use the current time for the versionCode instead of trying to automatically increment the versionCode and check it into my revision control system.

Add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
/**
 * Use the number of seconds/10 since Jan 1 2016 as the versionCode.
 * This lets us upload a new build at most every 10 seconds for the
 * next 680 years.
 */
def vcode = (int)(((new Date().getTime()/1000) - 1451606400) / 10)

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode vcode
    }
}
```

However, if you expect to upload builds beyond year 2696, you may want to use a different solution.

Comment: If you are reading this now, and starting with a new app, you can substract `1510351294` :))

Comment: i dont get this !! dont you use analytics or crashlytics or any other service that gives data with version codes and names ? and you are playing with these this easily ?

Comment: If you have reasonable version names, I think it's fine. Crashalytics provide the version name as well.

Comment: @emmby where do you get the '1451606400' number from? or the '1510351294' from #Entreco  I have been trying to calculate in vain!

Comment: @JosephWambura it is just the current unix timestamp.

Comment: If you are reading this now and starting with a new app, you can subtract 1610737340

Answer (score 22):

Another way of getting a `versionCode` automatically is setting `versionCode` to the number of commits in the checked out `git` branch. It accomplishes following objectives:

1. `versionCode` is generated automatically and consistently on any machine (including a `Continuous Integration` and/or `Continuous Deployment` server).
2. App with this `versionCode` is submittable to GooglePlay.
3. Doesn't rely on any files outside of repo.
4. Doesn't push anything to the repo
5. Can be manually overridden, if needed

Using [gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) library to accomplish the above objectives. Add code below to your `build.gradle` file the `/app` directory:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.5.0'
    }
}

android {
/*
    if you need a build with a custom version, just add it here, but don't commit to repo,
    unless you'd like to disable versionCode to be the number of commits in the current branch.

    ex. project.ext.set("versionCodeManualOverride", 123)
*/
    project.ext.set("versionCodeManualOverride", null)

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode getCustomVersionCode()
    }
}

def getCustomVersionCode() {

    if (project.versionCodeManualOverride != null) {
        return project.versionCodeManualOverride
    }

    // current dir is <your proj>/app, so it's likely that all your git repo files are in the dir
    // above.
    ext.repo = Grgit.open(project.file('..'))

    // should result in the same value as running
    // git rev-list <checked out branch name> | wc -l
    def numOfCommits = ext.repo.log().size()
    return numOfCommits
}
```

NOTE: For this method to work, it's best to only deploy to Google Play Store from the same branch (ex. `master`).

Comment: while in essence an elegent solution, I can imagine that this would slow down the build time drastically, depending on what exactly is happening in the 2 git lines. Any experience on that ?

Comment: I don't notice any performance improvement if this step is disabled. Have been using method locally and on our build machines for over a year and performance hasn't been an issue whatsoever. If you do notice any performance issues, do let me know!

Comment: While your solution is elegant, it could give some nasty unexpected surprises. It's critical that versionCodes are always larger than in the previous release. What if you have one branch with 50 commits, and you then create another branch which is newer but only have 40 commits, perhaps due to squashing a number of commits from some merged feature. I can see plenty of reasons your commit history would not always be a linear stream of incremental commits.

Comment: @JHH Those results aren't unexpected. As I mentioned in a note, this method works best when deploying from the same branch.

Comment: I would say, why not add the branch to the version "just to be sure".... so you have version "master-123".

Answer (score 14):

Recently I was working on a gradle plugin for Android that makes generating **versionCode** and **versionName** automatically. there are lots of customization. here you can find more info about it 
https://github.com/moallemi/gradle-advanced-build-version

Comment: This is a great plugin! Thanks for sharing 

Answer (score 14):

Create new file inside `<yourProjectLocation>/app/version.properties`

```
MAJOR=0
MINOR=0
PATCH=1
VERSION_CODE=1
```

Add following lines in `build.gradle` (Module file) :

```
android {
    // other properties....
    // add following lines...

    def _versionCode=0
    def _major=0
    def _minor=0
    def _patch=0

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        _patch = versionProps['PATCH'].toInteger() + 1
        _major = versionProps['MAJOR'].toInteger()
        _minor = versionProps['MINOR'].toInteger() 
        _versionCode= versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()+1
        
        if(_patch==100) {
            _patch=0
            _minor=_minor+1
        }
        if(_minor == 10){
            _minor = 0
            _major =_major + 1
        }

        versionProps['MAJOR']=_major.toString()
        versionProps['MINOR']=_minor.toString()
        versionProps['PATCH']=_patch.toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=_versionCode.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    }
    else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    def _versionName = "${_major}.${_minor}.${_patch}(${_versionCode})"

    defaultConfig {
        // other properties...
        // change only these two lines

        versionCode _versionCode
        versionName _versionName
    }
}
```

Output : `0.0.1(1)`

Comment: Thanks. And why have you inserted a versionCode into versionName? Even at the second position.

Comment: But it will look like 1.71.3.76, for instance. I think, better is 1.3.76, separating it from version code.

Comment: Yes . you can change to "${_major}..${_minor}.${_patch}.${_versionCode}" or remove patch

Comment: if(_major==99) should be if(_minor==99) ??

Answer (score 11):

Another option, for incrementing the `versionCode` and the `versionName`, is using a timestamp.

```
defaultConfig {
   versionName "${getVersionNameTimestamp()}"
   versionCode getVersionCodeTimestamp()
}


def getVersionNameTimestamp() {
    return new Date().format('yy.MM.ddHHmm')
}

def getVersionCodeTimestamp() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyMMddHHmm')
    def code = formattedDate.toInteger()
    println sprintf("VersionCode: %d", code)
    return code
}
```

Starting on January,1 2022
formattedDate = date.format('yyMMddHHmm')
exceeds the capacity of Integers

Comment: The person wanted an auto-increment build number

Comment: @peter_pilgrim Caro is the OP.

Comment: I think is this is an elegant solution, it doesnt rely on files that might vanish or not or that will constantly show up in git. It also helps you to uniquely identify each build for atleast the next dozen 22 years.

Comment: quoting developer.android.com:"Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for versionCode is 2100000000. " So, the cutoff is actually 2021.

Comment: Fix for int limit: omit minutes and use date format 'yyMMddHH', the version code will contain at least hours.

Comment: For anyone now using this approach, it has broken if you included minutes.

Answer (score 11):

To increment versionCode only in release version do it:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def code = 1;
    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();
        def value = 0
        for (String item : runTasks)
        if ( item.contains("assembleRelease")) {
            value = 1;
        }
        code = Integer.parseInt(versionProps['VERSION_CODE']).intValue() + value
        versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    }
    else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pack"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionName "1.0."+ code
        versionCode code
    }
```

expects an existing `c://YourProject/app/version.properties` file, which you would create by hand before the first build to have `VERSION_CODE=8`

File 
`version.properties`:

`VERSION_CODE=8`

Comment: Rather put it inside a task and make the generateReleaseBuildConfig depends on that task.

Comment: versionName "1.0."+ getSvnRevision() causes an error. Where is the getSvnRevision() method referencing to? Are you sure it shouldn't be versionName "1.0."+ code (the version name will increase with your version code)?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder, replace getSvnRevision()  to code

Answer (score 4):

Examples shown above don't work for different reasons

Here is my ready-to-use variant based on ideas from this article:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405457

    def propsFile = file("version.properties")
    // Default values would be used if no file exist or no value defined
    def customAlias = "Alpha"
    def customMajor = "0"
    def customMinor = "1"
    def customBuild = "1" // To be incremented on release

    Properties props = new Properties()
    if (propsFile .exists())
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile ))

    if (props['ALIAS'] == null) props['ALIAS'] = customAlias else customAlias = props['ALIAS']
    if (props['MAJOR'] == null) props['MAJOR'] = customMajor else customMajor = props['MAJOR']
    if (props['MINOR'] == null) props['MINOR'] = customMinor else customMinor = props['MINOR']
    if (props['BUILD'] == null) props['BUILD'] = customBuild else customBuild = props['BUILD']

    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.join(",").contains('assembleRelease')) {
        customBuild = "${customBuild.toInteger() + 1}"
        props['BUILD'] = "" + customBuild

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                if (output.outputFile != null && (output.outputFile.name == "app-release.apk"))
                    outputFileName = "app-${customMajor}-${customMinor}-${customBuild}.apk"
            }
        }
    }

    props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), "Incremental Build Version")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode customBuild.toInteger()
        versionName "$customAlias $customMajor.$customMinor ($customBuild)"

        ...
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define **versionName** in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:versionName="5.1.5"
```

Inside `android{...}` block in `build.gradle` of app level :

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.autoincrement"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        def version = getIncrementationVersionName()
        versionName version
}
```

Outside `android{...}` block in `build.gradle` of app level :

```
def getIncrementedVersionName() {
    List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();

    //find version name in manifest
    def manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    def matcher = Pattern.compile('versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"').matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()

    //extract versionName parts
    def firstPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def secondPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2))
    def thirdPart = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3))

    //check is runTask release or not
    // if release - increment version
    for (String item : runTasks) {
        if (item.contains("assemble") && item.contains("Release")) {
            thirdPart++
            if (thirdPart == 10) {
                thirdPart = 0;
                secondPart++
                if (secondPart == 10) {
                    secondPart = 0;
                    firstPart++
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def versionName = firstPart + "." + secondPart + "." + thirdPart

    // update manifest
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll('versionName=\"' + versionName + '\"')
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)

    println "incrementVersionName = " + versionName

    return versionName
}
```

After create singed APK :

```
android:versionName="5.1.6"
```

Note : If your **versionName** different from my, you need change **regex** and **extract parts logic**.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to 
CommonsWare (Accepted Answer)
Paul Cantrell (Create file if it doesn't exist)
ahmad aghazadeh (Version name and code)

So I mashed all their ideas together and came up with this.  This is the drag and drop solution to exactly what the first post asked.

It will automatically update the versionCode and versionName according to release status.  Of course you can move the variables around to suite your needs.

```
def _versionCode=0
def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
if(versionPropsFile.exists())
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    def _patch = (versionProps['PATCH'] ?: "0").toInteger() + 1
    def _major = (versionProps['MAJOR'] ?: "0").toInteger()
    def _minor = (versionProps['MINOR'] ?: "0").toInteger()
    List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();
    def value = 0
    for (String item : runTasks)
        if ( item.contains("assembleRelease")) {
            value = 1;
        }
    _versionCode = (versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] ?: "0").toInteger() + value
    if(_patch==99)
    {
        _patch=0
        _minor=_minor+1
    }
    if(_major==99){
        _major=0
        _major=_major+1
    }

versionProps['MAJOR']=_major.toString()
versionProps['MINOR']=_minor.toString()
versionProps['PATCH']=_patch.toString()
versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=_versionCode.toString()
versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
def _versionName = "${_major}.${_versionCode}.${_minor}.${_patch}"

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourhost.yourapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode _versionCode
    versionName _versionName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions I really like. The first depends on the Play Store and the other depends on Git.

Using the Play Store, you can increment the version code by looking at the highest available *uploaded* version code. The benefit of this solution is that an APK upload will never fail since your version code is always one higher than whatever is on the Play Store. The downside is that distributing your APK outside of the Play Store becomes more difficult. You can set this up using Gradle Play Publisher by following the [quickstart guide](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/blob/master/README.md#quickstart-guide) and telling the plugin to [resolve version codes automatically](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/blob/master/README.md#handling-version-conflicts):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.github.triplet.play' version 'x.x.x'
}

android {
    ...
}

play {
    serviceAccountCredentials = file("your-credentials.json")
    resolutionStrategy = "auto"
}
```

Using Git, you can increment the version code based on how many commits and tags your repository has. The benefit here is that your output is reproducible and doesn't depend on anything outside your repo. The downside is that you have to make a new commit or tag to bump your version code. You can set this up by adding the [Version Master Gradle plugin](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/version-master/blob/master/README.md#installation):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.supercilex.gradle.versions' version 'x.x.x'
}

android {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the new version in a properties file, I created a Gradle task that can update the current `versionName` and `versionCode` automatically and also can get the new version string from command line (by passing arguments to the task with `-P` followed by *<argName>=<argValue>*).

app *build.gradle.kts*:

```kotlin
project.version = "1.2.3"

tasks.create("incrementVersion") {
    group = "versioning"
    description = "Increments the version to make the app ready for next release."
    doLast {
        var (major, minor, patch) = project.version.toString().split(".")
        val mode = project.properties["mode"]?.toString()?.toLowerCaseAsciiOnly()
        if (mode == "major") {
            major = (major.toInt() + 1).toString()
            minor = "0"
            patch = "0"
        } else if (mode == "minor") {
            minor = (minor.toInt() + 1).toString()
            patch = "0"
        } else {
            patch = (patch.toInt() + 1).toString()
        }
        var newVersion = "$major.$minor.$patch"

        val overrideVersion = project.properties["overrideVersion"]?.toString()?.toLowerCaseAsciiOnly()
        overrideVersion?.let { newVersion = it }

        val newBuild = buildFile
            .readText()
            .replaceFirst(Regex("version = .+"), "version = \"$newVersion\"")
            .replaceFirst(Regex("versionName = .+\""), "versionName = \"$newVersion\"")
            .replaceFirst(Regex("versionCode = \\d+"), "versionCode = ${(android.defaultConfig.versionCode ?: 0) + 1}")
        buildFile.writeText(newBuild)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```sh
gradlew incrementVersion [-P[mode=major|minor|patch]|[overrideVersion=x.y.z]]
```

Examples:

```sh
gradlew :app:incrementVersion -Pmode=major
```

```sh
gradlew :app:incrementVersion -PoverrideVersion=4.5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Gradle Task Graph** we can check/switch **build type.**

The basic idea is to increment the **versionCode** on each build. On Each build a counter stored in the **version.properties** file. It will be keep updated on every new APK build and replace versionCode string in the **build.gradle** file with this incremented counter value.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
def versionBuild

/*Setting default value for versionBuild which is the last incremented value stored in the file */
if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger()
} else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
}


/*Wrapping inside a method avoids auto incrementing on every gradle task run. Now it runs only when we build apk*/
ext.autoIncrementBuildNumber = {

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
        versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.nminSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1ewWriter(), null)
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }
}


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0." + versionBuild
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

// Hook to check if the release/debug task is among the tasks to be executed.
//Let's make use of it
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(assembleDebug)) {  /* when run debug task */
        autoIncrementBuildNumber()
    } else if (taskGraph.hasTask(assembleRelease)) { /* when run release task */
        autoIncrementBuildNumber()
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Place the above script inside your build.gradle file of main module.

Answer (score 0):

> The First Commented code will increment the number while each "Rebuild Project" and save the the value in the "Version Property" file.
>
> The Second Commented code will generate new version name of APK file while "Build APKs".

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    //==========================START==================================
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if(versionPropsFile.exists())
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    def code = (versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] ?: "0").toInteger() + 1
    versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    //===========================END===================================
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.19"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //=======================================START===============================================
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    def appName = "MyAppSampleName"
                    outputFileName = appName+"_v${variant.versionName}.${versionProps['VERSION_CODE']}.apk"
                }
            }
            //=======================================END===============================================
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some text showing what you've changed. and why

Answer (score 0):

in the Gradle 5.1.1 version on mac ive changed how the task names got retrieved, i althought tried to get build flavour / type from build but was to lazy to split the task name:

```
def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    def value = 0

    def runTasks = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    if (runTasks.contains('assemble') || runTasks.contains('assembleRelease') || runTasks.contains('aR')) {
        value = 1
    }

    def versionMajor = 1
    def versionMinor = 0
    def versionPatch = versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value
    def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
    def versionNumber = versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value

    versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = versionPatch.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = versionNumber.toString()

    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.evomotion.ms10"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode versionNumber
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild})"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

} else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}
```

code is from @just_user
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23265711/11016337)