# android studio gradle version increment

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to setup a nice little versioning script in gradle, android studio where the version name increases every time I make a build, while the version code only increases when I make a release build. Is this possible?

What I think would solve it is checking in the if statement below if it is a release or not. But how can I check if it is a release?

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
def code
def name
def Properties versionProps

if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1
    name = versionProps['VERSION_NAME'].toInteger() + 1

    versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_NAME']=name.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode code
        versionName "1.2." + name
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        ...
    }
    releaseKey {
        ...
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseKey
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

I would like something like:

```
if (release) code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + 1
else code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a few hours of trial and error I figured out a way this can be done.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    def value = 0

    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
        value = 1;
    }

    def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + value
    def name = versionProps['VERSION_NAME'].toInteger() + 1

    versionProps['VERSION_CODE']=code.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_NAME']=name.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode code
        versionName "1.2." + name
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        ...
    }
    releaseKey {
        ...
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
    }

    release {
        ...
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
```

So what I'm doing is to check if I'm doing a assebleRelease task or not. If I am I increase the versionCode with +1.

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: Can we have a look at your version.properties file

Comment: I know whats in it but just to be sure

Comment: @Bhargav http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405457/autoincrement-versioncode-with-gradle-extra-properties/23265711#23265711

Comment: check my answer there, its a bit more detailed

Comment: ah thanks! you are over writing the file even if it exists that way if it doesn't exist its created