# Android/gradle: include version name from flavor in apk file name

Tags: android, gradle

I have found similar questions but nothing that quite works for what I want to do.  I'm developing with Android Studio and gradle, and I have several flavors in my build file, each of which has a versionName.  Is there a way to include the flavor's version name in the APK file?

Comment: Your question title refers to a version number; your question body refers to a version name. In Android, those are separate things. Which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDIT: For modern versions of the Gradle tools, use @ptx's variation (use `output.outputFile` in place of `variant.outputFile`:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parentFile,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "${variant.versionName}.apk"));
        }
    }
}
```

---

As of Gradle tools plugin version 0.14, you should start using the following instead to properly support multiple output files (e.g. APK Splits):

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            variant.outputFile = new File(variant.outputFile.parentFile,
                    variant.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "${variant.versionName}.apk"));
        }
    }
}
```

For older versions:

---

Yeah, we do this in our app. Just add the following in your android tag in build.gradle:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def oldFile = variant.outputFile
        def newPath = oldFile.name.replace(".apk", "${variant.versionName}.apk")
        variant.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parentFile, newPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

kcoppock's answer is correct, but there is a small typo.
It should be:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parentFile,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "${variant.versionName}.apk"));
        }
    }
}
```

(I wrote this as an answer because I don't have the reputation to make a comment)

Comment: I'm not sure it was a mistake, I think with the change to Android Studio 1.0, or perhaps a newer version of gradle or the build tools, the details of how to do this changed.  I have been using basically what you wrote and it's working great.