# Custom Task in Gradle (Android)

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

(gradle newbie question)

I am looking to run a custom task with code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405457/autoincrement-versioncode-with-gradle-extra-properties). This is to do with setting up build env for release/debug etc...

Since the code bloats the original boilerplate code, I would like to do following for readability and extensibility -

1. Move the code to separate file as a task/def([Gist of the Code](https://gist.github.com/metamrudul/47cefb15c8987057f4b3)
2. Run the task/def before assembleDebug/Release

Here are problems I face when task is appended at the end of build.gradle file:

a) If I run just the task ./gradlew buildCustom , I get error

> Could not find method defaultConfig() for arguments

b) If I try to use doLast I get error

> Could not find method doLast() for arguments [task ':app:assembleDebug'] on task ':app:buildCustom'.

There is something very obvious that I donot understand, appreciate any help.

Comment: Is better that you post your Gist here.

Comment: wouldn't it pollute the space over here? I think putting in gist helps me separate code from query