# Android Build Tools only builds x86_64 no matter what. APK runs installed via adb, but shows incompatible on Play Store

Tags: android, gradle, build, build-tools

So this is happening. No matter what I try doing on the build.gradle, all APK are coming out with `native_code = 'x86_64'` flag, so when I deploy the app to the store the result is having +15K uncompatible devices, and only 19 compatible. I first thought that, somehow, having NDK installed was the reason, or my modified build script. But it still happens when I go through the Generate Signed APK wizard. The `splits` block was also originally missing, and didn't help. The weirdest thing is that when I install via a console push, IT WORKS!

[image: WTF!]
[image: WTF2!]

I also tried switching to the recommended JRE, also several APK naming strategies regarding file creation, like moving the output to different directories or not using the file constructor.

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.chiskosystems.brokr"
    versionCode versionNumber
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch} (${versionBuild}) Release"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

    jackOptions {
        enabled false
    }

    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}

project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3]

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def fileNaming = "apk/brokr"
        def outputFile = output.outputFile

        output.versionCodeOverride =
                project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                        com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode

    }

}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        try {
            storeFile file('../mystore.jks')
            keyAlias 'release'
            storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        } catch (ex) {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("You should define KEYSTORE_PASSWORD and KEY_PASSWORD in gradle.properties.")
        }
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    preDexLibraries false
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFile 'path/proguard-project.pro'
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", 'SERVER', '"https://myfirebaseserver.com"'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        buildConfigField "String", 'SERVER', '"https://myfirebaseserver.com"'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

productFlavors {
    sandbox {
        buildConfigField "String", 'PAYPAL_ENV', '"PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK"'
    }
    full {
        buildConfigField "String", 'PAYPAL_ENV', '"PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION"'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}
```

Happening on both Win and Unix systems. I've spent the whole day modifiyng the script without success and I'm helpless at this point.

Any ideas of what the *bleep* is going on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just an initial thought, `applicationVariants.all { variant -> variant.outputs.each`, could this maybe be overwriting the .apk's with only the last build which in this case might be x86_64. I remember having a similar problem a while back. What I've had to do is to look for an identifier and only write that for the specific build.

Comment: @just_user So doing kind of like a switch for archs inside that block?

Comment: Exactly, but I'd test it first. Remove x86_64 from the building to see if all builds are just x86 then or one of the others.

Comment: Following @just_user advice, removed x86 support as I don't really need it. Result is the same

Comment: @just_user I tried doing the switch you mentioned but I could figure out if I need to compare a property inside `variant.outputs` or against a string. Could you please be more specific? :)

Comment: So I copied the build script into a new project and now the native_code flag is not set at all. This is weird as ****

Comment: I've tried your script too and haven't been able to have it working. But if you get no native_code flag set, try `gradle clean`?

Comment: No those don't work either, also did reset cachés

Comment: Double-check the permissions listed in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Last time I had *0 apps supported* at Google Play, it was caused by a typo in `android.hardware.camera`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JPVentura but the Manifest is typo-free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause was a dependency:

```
compile 'com.lambdaworks:scrypt:1.4.0'
```

apparently automatically grabbing my laptop's architecture and sticking that flag in there.

Comment: Wow, glad you found the cause. What an annoying error!