# Google Play - You need to use a different version code for your APK

Tags: android, google-play

I know this question has beed asked a few times, but it seems like any other solution does not work for me.

I'm supposed to update an app we have on the Google Play Store.
The version name and code are maintained in the gradle.build with this piece of code:

```
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 1
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 1

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    }
}
```

The current version from the store is 1.0.7(.5) which translates to 10705.
I'm supposed to update to 1.1.0(.1), which translates to 11001.

But the Google Play keeps telling me that I already have an APK with this version number. I checked every version of the app, back to 1.0.0 and I don't have any version with that number (obviously), since it is automatically calculated.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have another app, with a different package name, made for another client, that have this version code. But version codes are independant, right?

EDIT:
Couldn't find a solution. 
I negociated with my boss to update the version code to 1.1.0(.2) instead. And it worked. Still don't know why the GPlay thought the 1.1.0(.1) already exist, since it doesn't.

Comment: Did an app with that version get published to your alpha or beta channels?

Comment: No. The alpha was never used. And Beta channels used 0.0.x version, so between 1 and 100.

Comment: Have you uploaded any version at PlayStore ?

Comment: Check if there are any apk in your library that has not yet been publicated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405457/autoincrement-versioncode-with-gradle-extra-properties 
Try this link once...

Comment: Even if you have submitted your app with the version code and got rejected for some reasons, you have to increase the version code the next time.

Comment: @ViramP I already have a 10705 version code uploaded, but no trace of a 11001.

Comment: @GuilhermeFGL Already did. There isn't.

Comment: @RahulGupta Doesn't help, at all.

Comment: @Bob Nothing got rejected.