# Android get top level module details in base module in android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have two different app in one android project, as they both use similar components. One is client app and other is admin app. I also have an base module which constis of common util classes, ui components and other shared code.
Let say App1, App2 and BaseModule. Now I want to access `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` of App1 or App2 depending on which app is build, in base module. How to access it. Do I need some gradle script to transfer current app version_code to base mode?

I am trying to use shared preferances to share version code. But is there any to use it like `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`

Comment: You can pass `VERSION_CODE` to your base module. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21405744/12153321

Comment: Thanks, @Javlon. This answer is helpful.