# Update Android Application version (stored in build.gradle) with gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

It is possible to update the Android or library version `versionCode` and `versionName` when executing some task in gradle ? The versionCode/Name is placed in my android/build.gradle

I'm searching for a complete gradle script, not a shell one.

It's different from [How to autoincrement versionCode in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448565/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle) because the versionCode and versioName is stored in the build.gradle not in the manifest

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoincrement versionCode in Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448565/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle)

Comment: @EdGeorge It's different from How to autoincrement versionCode in Android Gradle because the versionCode and versioName is stored in the build.gradle not in the manifest

Comment: The post above shows techniques for both, should this be different to any of those solutions and completes the same task, it should be posted as an answer on that question and not as its own question

Comment: @EdGeorge the question specify by editing `AndroidManifest.xml`. When searching for this solution I haven't find any answer, and the "posibble duplicate" did not output during my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.gradle you want to update, I've changed a script to edit the current build.gradle and incrementing the versionCode and versionName.

Add this task to your gradle :

```
task incrementVersionCode << {
    println("Incrementing Version Code...")
    def manifestFile = file("build.gradle")
    def patternVersionCode = Pattern.compile("versionCode (\\d+)")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionCode = patternVersionCode.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionCode.find()
    def mVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionCode.group(1))
    def mNextVersionCode = mVersionCode + 1
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionCode.replaceAll("versionCode " + mNextVersionCode)
    println("> Set versionCode(" + mVersionCode + ") to " + mNextVersionCode);
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

task incrementVersionName << {
    println("Incrementing Version Name...")
    def manifestFile = file("build.gradle")
    def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName \"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionNumber.find()
    def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
    def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
    def pointVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
    def mVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + pointVersion
    def mNextVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + (pointVersion + 1)
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionNumber.replaceAll("versionName \"" + mNextVersionName + "\"")
    println("> Set versionName(" + mVersionName + ") to " + mNextVersionName);
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}
```

**Usage**

If you want to update version when running `./gradlew bintrayUpload` (for eg, mut it can be the task you want) add this :

```
bintrayUpload.dependsOn incrementVersionCode
bintrayUpload.dependsOn incrementVersionName
```