# Auto increment versioncode only on releases

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Currently I'm trying to improve our buildscript with auto incrementing the versioncode so our QA team has got a clue what build they are testing and can log against a specific versioncode. We have got 3 productFlavors (staging, qa, production) and 2  signing configs (debug, release).

I looked into different solutions:

[How to autoincrement versionCode in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448565/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle/26091797)

[How to autoincrement versionCode in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448565/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle/17525195)

[Autoincrement VersionCode with gradle extra properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405457/autoincrement-versioncode-with-gradle-extra-properties/28043555)

Based on those answers I've built a versioncode incrementor using a version.properties file.

Now the problem arises that for EVERY productFlavor and SigningConfig combination (+ the gradle sync in android studio) a new versioncode is generated. I want the versioncode to increment whenever I hit the play button to create a qaRelease build. So our buildcycle would be:

- development (never change the versioncode)
- qual (Update the versioncode)
- production (never change the versioncode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like that

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern    
task('increaseVersionCode') << {

    ... // You could code in your increment system, for eg

    // Using build.gradle (recommended)
    def buildFile = file("build.gradle")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode\\s+(\\d+)")
    def manifestText = buildFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode " + ++versionCode)
    buildFile.write(manifestContent)


    // Using manifest
    def manifestFile = file('AndroidManifest.xml')
    def matcher = Pattern.compile('versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"')
    .matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll('versionCode=\"' +
    ++Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + '\"')
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}



tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleQaRelease') {
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
    }
}
```

You can adapt the 'assembleQaRelease' to increment version code to the wanted task.

Comment: With `file("build.gradle")` you mean the android manifest file instead of the build.gradle?

Comment: That's depend when you set your version code. It's a good practice to define it in the build.gradle, which override the manifest one.

Comment: I edited my answer. Just pick the solution adapted to your project ;)

Comment: I'll take yours as an accepted answer because you set me on the right track. But I did it somewhat else and I'm going to add that also in a solution :)

Answer (score 8):

How I solved it:

- I created a file version.properties in the root of my android project and added the versioncode in it.
- Then I created method called getCurrentVersionCode() in my build.gradle file that reads the current versioncode.

Code:

```
def getCurrentVersionCode() {
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

    return versionProps['version_code'].toInteger()
}
```

I also created a method to generate a new code:

Code:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523393/auto-increment-versioncode-only-on-releases
//
def setUpdatedVersionCode() {
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    def code = getCurrentVersionCode() + 1

    versionProps['version_code'] = code.toString()
    versionProps['version_name'] = generateVersionName()

    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
}
```

and then I created a task that triggers on a QA build.

Code:

```
task('increaseVersionCode') << {
    setUpdatedVersionCode()
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleQaRelease') {
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
    }
}
```

That way it saves the versioncode in a separate file so I don't need to edit my build.gradle.

Comment: Is there anything special to get gradle to read the version.properties file you created in the root of your project folder? I am unable to get gradle to read this file.

Comment: Is this impossible to do?