# How to change or replace version of gradle using task in java project?

Tags: java, grails, gradle, command-line

I have a gradle project and I want to **UPDATE** its version by building a task so that when ever i run that task it **UPDATE** the version number in `gradle.properties` file automatically:

**THIS:**

`ServiceVer=1.0.0 ServiceSnapshot=-SNAPSHOT`

**Should change like:**

`ServiceVer=2.0.0 ServiceSnapshot=-SNAPSHOT`

what task do i need to write or any basic and easy example(link) to understand?
i am new to gradle.
i want to have all these changes in a java project not in an android project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autoincrement versionCode in Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448565/how-to-autoincrement-versioncode-in-android-gradle)

Comment: somewhat similar but i want to do it for java application not android. and thanks for the link, little bit helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to update the properties file

```
task versionPlusPlus() << {
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new File('gradle.properties').newDataInputStream())
    versionString =  props.getProperty('ServiceVer')
    //  mutate versionString to whatever you want
    props.setProperty('ServiceVer', versionString)
    props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
}
```

I haven't tested this, but you may want to be careful about calling this task and running a build in the same gradle invocation (for instance `gradle versionPlusPlus build`, the new versionString may not take effect; run `gradle versionPlusPlus` and then `gradle build` separately after gradle.properties is updated.

For the updated version to take effect within the same gradle invocation set `project.version=ServiceVar` after changing the version string.

Comment: it does nothing. tried both `props.setProperty` and `System.setProperty`

Comment: I intended for this to be used in subsequent runs before I added the sysprops note. run `gradle versionplusplus` followed by `gradle build`. Does that not work either?